# How can I fix this value error: Incomplete wav chunk error?

Tags: python, scipy, noise-reduction

I am trying to do a noise reduction in an audio wave file using the code below;

```
import noisereduce as nr
from scipy.io import wavfile

# load data
rate, data = wavfile.read("output.wav")
# select section of data that is noise
noisy_part = data[10000:15000]
# perform noise reduction
reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(audio_clip=data, noise_clip=noisy_part, verbose=True)
```

But I keep on getting the error below;

```
File "C:\...\noisereduce.py", line 5, in <module> rate, data = wavfile.read("output.wav")
ValueError: Incomplete wav chunk.
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Yes this has been of help.

Comment: changing this number "4" to "1" in the file wavefile.py file, in this condition of the code seems to solve the issue:
- len(chunk_id) < 1